# adapt single_machine_scheduling_with_setup_release_due_dates_sat for multiple machines

Tags: or-tools

what is the correct strategy for adapting the single_machine_scheduling_with_setup_release_due_dates_sat to work on a multiple machines scenario?

Is the CircuitConstraint still an option?

ive been trying to put the job shop problem to work on a context that any job could not start if any other job, from the same machine or not, has ended on previous duration unit? (for example, to give a duration to clean the floor before the machine starts to work)
the "setup time" on the example is somehow what i need.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [jobshop with distance](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/jobshop_ft06_distance_sat.py) example.

If you want to see how to use the circuit with optional tasks, have a look at the generic [jobshop runner](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/cpp/jobshop_sat.cc).